# Homomorphism between Fix(Cube) and $S_4$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\mathrm{Fix}(\mathrm{Cube}):=\{F\text{ isometry}\;|\;F(\mathrm{cube})=\mathrm{cube} \}$. We know $\#G=48$ which I counted by multiplying the numbers of such F that fix a vertex by the possible destinations of the vertex.

Prove there exist a surjective homomorphism $G\rightarrow S_4$ by identifying the elements of $S_4$ with the permutations of the diagonals of the cube.

Manually I think I've shown the homomorphism, by identifing the image of the generators of $G$ and tring some compositions between these.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is just that any isometry $F$ of the cube induces a permutation $\sigma$ of the set of diagonals, by sending a diagonal $[A,B]$ to $\sigma([A,B])=[F(A),F(B)]$ (prove it). Of course, the natural homomorphism $\phi:G\to S_4$ is the one defined by $\phi(F)=\sigma$. You can check that it's a homomorphism without trying out all the combinations of the generators: let $F$ and $F'$ be symmetries of the cube, $\sigma=\phi(F)$, $\sigma'=\phi(F')$; you want to show that $\phi(F'\circ F)=\sigma'\circ\sigma$.

**Hint:** Look closely at how $\sigma=\phi(F)$ is defined, just write out $\phi(F'\circ F)([A,B])$ and compare it to $(\sigma'\circ\sigma)([A,B])$.

Also, you could count the order of $G$ another way: find the kernel of $\phi$ (which is not too much trouble), and then use $|G|/|\ker\phi|=|S_4|$.